# Are PCIe device drivers beneficial if using Linux as a bootloader for bare-metal code?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bootloader, pci-e, bare-metal

I am developing an embedded system on a PowerPC processor and there is need for communication with an FPGA via PCIe. I wish to use Linux/embedded-Linux as a bootloader to leverage its PCIe initialization code and driver API for simplified PCIe driver development. However in the end I want to be running bare-metal code (no OS running). So I am looking at using PetitBoot/kexec to jump from Linux to my own code.

Is this possible?

My current understanding of PCIe drivers leads me to believe that once the device is initialized, so long as I have a pointer to the address space, I should be able to simply execute MMIO R/W operations directly to the memory space. So even if kexec overwrites the driver code I should be able to use the device because the driver has done its job already.

Is this correct?

If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: If you need PCIe framework in bare-metal code, maybe you can find such code in u-boot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took a short look into u-boot as suggested. However I'm working with a very new cpu and I don't believe uboot is configured for it or my board. There is a customized buildroot environment that exists for my CPU/board that I am trying to work around and the 'BIOS' boots embedded Linux, which in turn uses PetitBoot to load a full Linux OS. So I was considering adding a device driver to the embedded linux and using PetitBoot to load my bare-metal code instead of the full Linux OS. My assumption is that customizing uboot would be duplicating the buildroot efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this approach would be a good idea. Drivers that were written with the Linux OS in mind are going to assume that all of the OS's resources are available, not just memory allocations. For example, it may configure interrupt handlers, but when the OS is not longer available, your hardware may get hung because nothing is acknowledging and servicing its interrupt requests.

I'm skeptical of the memory initialization as well. I suppose you could theoretically allocate some DMA memory and pass the resulting physical address to your bare-metal application as it takes over, but the whole process seems sketchy. It would be very difficult to make sure everything in Linux is shut down cleanly while leaving the PCIe subsystem running. You'll have to look at the driver's shut down routines and see what it does to the card to make sure it doesn't shut down the device and make it unresponsive to your bare-metal code.

I would suggest that you instead go through the Linux-based driver and use it as a guide to construct a new bare-metal driver. Copy the initialization code that you need, and leave out the Linux-specific configuration details.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went with your suggestion to develop the bare metal code.